# String encoding issue with pyodbc's returned data

Tags: python, encoding, ubuntu-14.04, pyodbc, string-decoding

On making query with PyODBC, I am getting my table data as:

```
 u'\u3836\u3431\u3132\u3230\u3030'
```

The actual content in my database column is as:

```
 6814210200
```

When I explicitly encode `pyodbc`'s returned value to `utf-16`, I get the content as (closest I went):

```
>>> print d['data'][0]['upc'].encode('utf-16')
 ��6814210200
#^^ two junks
```

**My question is: How can I get the encoded value directly from the PyODBC query?**

I already have `CHARSET=UTF16` set in my database connection string as:

```
pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=<driver_name>;" + \
                                 "SERVER=<server_ip>;" +\
                                 "DATABASE=<database>;" +\
                                 "UID=<user>;" +\
                                 "PWD=<password>;" + \
                                 "CHARSET=UTF16",    # setting charset
                                 ansi=True)
```

Also in all my `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` file, I have set:

```
 UnicodeTranslationOption = utf16 
 CharacterTranslationOption = all
```

under my driver's setting.

Comment: Is there some special reason that you're using UTF-16? That's not very common, and almost unheard of on Linux systems. What happens if you set `"CHARSET=UTF8"`?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant to your particular situation (and I know nothing about PyODBC), but there's a lot of good info about Unicode (both for Python 2 & Python 3) in this article: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM2Ring `"CHARSET=UTF8"` also returns the same result. The reason for using `UTF-16` is I am using Nettezza's Database driver which is based on UTF-16 codec. And thanks for sharing the article, it looks interesting to me. Will take a look.

Comment: No need to use backslashes there! No need to use + even if strings are constant. Your data doesn't seem to be in UTF-16 - what do you *actually* get when you use `CHARSET=UTF8` - please add the **unmodified `repr` of that value**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I am using `.format()` in each line in actual code, that is the reason to use "+ \". The O/P I have given is the content of `repr()` as `u'\u3836\u3431\u3132\u3230\u3030'`, Without `repr`, it prints `㠶㐱ㄲ㈰〰`  (something in Chineese (looks like mandrin)) . And, I get the same content if I mention `CHARSET=UTF8` with the connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian) version of UTF-16.

```
s = u'\u3836\u3431\u3132\u3230\u3030'
print s.encode('utf-16le')
```

**output**

```
6814210200
```

FWIW, in Python 3, `s.encode('utf-16le')` returns `b'6814210200'`.

Comment: I do not want to explicitly encode value of each row and column returned by PyODBC query. I am looking for option to specify encoding in the PyODBC configuration/connection string, which implicitly handles the encoding part. Doing it explicitly will be huge over head. Anyway, +1 as PyODBC query part I have added later in the question.

Comment: In that case you may well need to get things sorted out at the database level.